# How to create a ListView with multiple text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Hey, I want to know how do I do to create a ListView in Android like this, not exactly, but with multiple text, and the text with different font size? Because the one I've created just worked for one text line for each line. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your listview contains items, and the items are views. You can make that view e.g. a linearlayout with two textviews, one bigger then the other!

By the way, the example you've got there is a `PreferenceScreen`, a special case. You probably don't need that info, but still, might be nice to know ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the view you want to use in XML and then inflate it in your list adapter. There's a brief but useful example [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/56268.aspx). Alternatively, check the API tutorial that came with the SDK. There should be several examples there that are easy to cut-and-paste into your project.